# upload video to linkedin via REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linkedin-api, omniauth, linkedin-jsapi

I want to upload video to linkedin from my rails application using REST API. Is there any method by which I can upload video to linkedin?

There is an option to share URL but that doesn't fulfills the requirements. I want to upload video and play that video in newsfeed.

Answer (score 2):

Linkedin does not allowed to upload video via rest api

Comment: This answer is outdated. Refer to these docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2023-03&tabs=http#how-to-upload-videos

Answer (score 0):

With api V2 can we share a video using api? using UPC post?
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/ugc-post-api
Saw examples of get/delete but not post

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/vector-asset-api
Above link has the step by step procedure on how to upload a video to linkedin and how you can create a post using that video